# fastify url regex with slashes

Tags: node.js, regex, url, routes, fastify

I'd like to define a fastify url route with regex like this

```
     fastify.get('/:myregex/products',{
                        schema: {
                            params :{
                                myregex : {
                                    type: 'string',
                                    pattern: '((\\w)+:(\\w)+)'
                                }
                            },
                            response: {}
                        }
                    },async (req, reply) => {
                      reply.send(req.params.myregex);
                    }
    });
```

if I try an url like `/param1:value1/param2:value2/param3:value3/products` in swagger it translate this in `/param1%3Avalue1%2Fparam2%3Avalue2%2Fparam3%3Avalue3/products` and it goes, BUT if i try my string in browser I have a 404
`{ "message": "Route GET:/param1:value1/param2:value2/param3:value3/products/products not found", "error": "Not Found", "statusCode": 404 }`

What am I doing wrong?

fastify": "^3.9.2"
node v12.20.1

Comment: The url for  which you get 404 ends with `/products/products` -> `GET:/param1:value1/param2:value2/param3:value3/products/products` is that intentional?

Comment: yes, the problem was about the lentgh of the query string

Answer (score 0):

You cannot archive what you need in that way because you are mapping a path parameter `myregex`, to an URL `param1:value1/param2:value2/param3:value3` since there are slashes `/` in your value and it is processed as an URL [as the standard said](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.2.3).

You need to change the `/` to another char, or change the URL pattern using the wildcard `*`:

```
const app = require('fastify')();

app.get('/:myregex/products', { schema: {} }, async (req, reply) => {
  reply.send(req.params);
})

app.get('/products/*', {
  schema: {
    params: {
      '*': {
        type: 'string',
        pattern: '((\\w)+:(\\w)+)'
      }
    }
  }
}, async (req, reply) => {
  reply.send(req.params);
})

app.inject('/param1:value1@param2:value2@param3:value3/products')
  .then(res => { console.log(res.json()); })
  .catch(err => { console.error(err) })

app.inject('/products/param1:value1/param2:value2/param3:value3')
  .then(res => { console.log(res.json()); })
  .catch(err => { console.error(err) })
```